# MongoDB database level sharding and not collection level sharding

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, sharding

Let's say I have 10 databases (1, 2, 3, ..., 9, 10) and a 2 shard MongoDB cluster.

I don't want to shard data at collection level but rather keep entire data of any given database on a given shard.

So I would like my MongoDB cluster to hold values like following (assume shard key to be odd even for simplicity) -
Shard 0: DB(1, 3, 5, 7, 9)
Shard 1: DB(2, 4, 6, 8, 10)

How do I achieve the same?

Comment: See this post: [primary shards in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38840456/primary-shards-in-mongodb). Also, note the feature to specify Primary Shard is "Available starting in MongoDB 4.2.2 (and 4.0.14)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call [enableSharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/enableSharding/) you can specify the primary shard for each database. Absent additional per-collection configuration, the data should be stored on those shards.

[movePrimary](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/movePrimary/) can be used to change a database's primary shard.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Not sure how I missed this in the Mongo docs. Thanks.